# Pass by reference need to have initial value?

Tags: c++, arguments, pass-by-reference

When a function's argument is passed by reference, does the the argument have to have an initial value? i wrote a small function that takes in an uin64_t by reference, but it crashed when i did `uint64_t a; func(VAL, a);\\ VAL is definitely defined`

the function simply gives `a` a new value, so there shouldnt be any problems with undefined values

Comment: Did you, perchance, compile in debug mode?

Comment: The fact you have written `int a;` means it has been initialized on the stack with the default parameterless constructor, it just hasn't been assigned an explicit value. The issue is with something else. Post the code and perhaps I can help.

Comment: @Vinnyq12: What do you mean by `has been initialized on the stack with the default parameterless constructor`?  Primitive types don't have constructor!

Comment: And if they did have constructors, then the parameterless constructor presumably would zero-initialize, since `int i = int();` results in `i == 0`.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on what you function does. If it tries to read the value in the parameter, you get undefined behavior. If you just assign to the parameter though, you are fine:

```
void func(int & var) {
    var = 5; // fine
}

void func(int & var) {
    std::cout << var << std::endl; // not fine
}
```

Comment: `func` is like the first function

Comment: and yet it crashed. it only stopped crashing when i did `uint64_t a = 0;` first

Comment: @calc: If you have a specific crash, then please show us the specific code that causes the crash.

Comment: serious question - while the value is undefined, there is a value assigned to the variable. why is this an issue?  (Sorry, I'm comparing this to how C does it, therefore my question)

Comment: Undefined behavior means that the compiler is free to do whatever it wants with your program. The behavior is simply not defined, and therefore anything can happen. You have no guarantees.

Comment: @Kevin it's undefined in C too.

Comment: I realize that it's undefined - but it won't make anything blow up - all by itself. it can make what happens later rather difficult to figure out though ;)

Comment: To expand on this, a value will be assigned, it's just unknown (undefined) what it will be.

Comment: @KevinDTimm : While maybe it _hasn't_ blown anything up, in your experience, that doesn't mean it _can't_... 'Undefined' means 'undefined', you've just been lucky.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing to do with references - use of unitialised variables usually results in undefined or at least unwanted behaviour. However, something like this is ok:

```
void f( int & x ) {
  x = 42;
}

int main() {
    int a;
    f( a );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading uninitialized variables invoke undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is no. The reason your application crashes is probably because a is not initialized. This is why it's important to always initialize variables.